# Is it possible to limit a user to only have access to a certain network interface?

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, vpn

I am running a CentOS 8 server, I want to create a user which only have network access to internet through VPN. Meaning that all applications used by this user ONLY can access the internet through VPN. While the rest of the users have access to only the "normal" network.
Where the VPN-tunnel uses interface tun0.

### Edit:

For anyone coming after me trying to do the same thing, this is how I did it: [Troubles using DNS with VPN split tunnel. CentOS 8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620033/troubles-using-dns-with-vpn-split-tunnel-centos-8)

Comment: Do you have a different interaces for accessing through VPN and to go direclty to the internet ?

Comment: Yes, tun0 is my vpn-interface

Comment: Since you have a different net interfaces you can use Iptables :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via `iptables`:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o VPN_INTERFACE -m owner --uid-owner USERNAME -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner USERNAME -j DROP # or REJECT
```

Notes:

- You could use `-I` instead of `-A` but then these two commands must be issued in the opposite order (since `-I` without arguments will insert a rule as the first).
- If you use `iptables -P OUTPUT DROP` (the default OUTPUT policy - don't allow anything) then only the first rule is necessary.

---

Via `firewalld`:

Via rich rules or/and `/etc/firewalld/direct.xml` (which is basically the same):

- https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.richlanguage.html
- https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/rhce-study-guide/firewalld-rich-rules-explained-with-examples.html
- https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/an-introduction-to-firewalld/

---

Don't forget about DNS. If you resolve domain names using an interface other than VPN, your user won't be able to access websites.

Comment: Will iptables be permeant or do I have to do the firewalld solution to make it permanent?

Comment: The `iptables` commands shown above apply only to your current session and disappear on reboot and if you have `firewalld` enabled you should add them to your firewall configuration.

Comment: Okay, I will try figure out how to set that up tomorrow. Will comment if I have more questions. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I do not manage to limit tun0 for only user vpn. Also how do I disable tun0 for the rest of the user? My current situation is that all users uses tun0... I'd like a permanent solution.

Comment: Did: `sudo firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner vpn -j ACCEPT` followed by `sudo firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -m owner --uid-owner vpn -j DROP`. Still when I run`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` I get my vpn-ip. But it seems like if the tun0 goes down, the vpn-user loses connection.

Comment: DNS normally works via UDP packets which are **always** sent from the root user. It's not trivial to to prevent the user from abusing/using DNS.

Comment: Okay, well I am now trying to follow the following guide: https://gist.github.com/GAS85/4e40ece16ffa748e7138b9aa4c37ca52

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it is correct for that I was asking at first.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a different NIcs as mentioned in the comment you can use iptables with -o for nic and --uid-owner :

Authorize Outound for VPN nic :

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o <vpn-nic> -m owner --uid-owner {<username>} -j ACCEPT
```

Drop Outbound for the other nics :

```
iptables -A INPUT  -m owner --uid-owner {<username>} -j REJECT
```

Make it permanent :

```
sudo iptables-save /etc/sysconfig/iptables
sudo chkconfig iptables on
```

Comment: `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` - this won't make these rules permanent. CentOS doesn't use this directory or file.

Comment: `iptables-save` will dump the rules on the screen and is also useless. Also centos 8 uses `firewalld` by default, so tinkering with iptables is useless.

Comment: you mean saving them to /etc/sysconfig/iptables ?

Comment: i didnt see 8 version i will update later thanks

Comment: Could you edit the question so I get a permanent solution? I am not able to figure this out on my own :(

Comment: Did: `sudo firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner vpn -j ACCEPT` followed by `sudo firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -m owner --uid-owner vpn -j DROP`. Still when I run`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` I get my vpn-ip. But it seems like if the tun0 goes down, the vpn-user loses connection.